# What is the distribution of the output of Metropolis Hastings algorithm at a fixed step?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, markov-chains

Given a targeted distribution $f(x)$, using Metropolis Hastings(MH) algorithm, assume at n-th step,
MH(n) will produce a number $T_n$. I understand that the sequence $T_n$ for $n = 1, 2, ...$ will have a distribution similar to the original distribution $f(x)$ when n is sufficient large.

Q: What is the distribution of $T_n$ itself when $n$ is sufficient large (or $n$ approaches infinity) ?

For example, if we choose a large $n$, $n = 1000000$, and if we run $T_{100000} = MH(100000)$ one billion times, what will be the distribution of $T_{100000}$ ?

I tried a few examples, and it seems that $T_n$ itself for sufficient large $n$ (but fixed $n$) also has a distribution similar to $f(x)$.
Is this observation CORRECT in general ?
If so, why is it ? Is there a proof for this ?

Answer (score 1):

In the setting of a finite state-space $\mathcal S$, with cardinal $|\mathcal S| = K$, the Markov chain $(T_n)_{n\ge0} $ can be represented by its transition matrix $P$ of size $K\times K$, defined as follows :
$$\forall(i,j)\in [\![ 1,K]\!]\times [\![ 1,K]\!],\ P_{i,j} := \mathbb{P}(T_1 = j\ |T_0 = i)$$
And in fact, since the Metropolis-Hastings transition kernel does not depend on time, in our case the transition probabilities are not time-dependent, i.e. :
$$\forall n \in \mathbb N, \ \forall(i,j)\in [\![ 1,K]\!]\times [\![ 1,K]\!],\ P_{i,j} := \mathbb{P}(T_{n+1} = j\ |T_n = i) $$

If we denote by $\left(\pi_n\right) =\left(\pi_n^{(1)},\ldots,\pi_n^{(K)}\right) $ the distribution of the Markov chain at time $n$, i.e. if we let
$$\forall n \in \mathbb N, \ \forall i \in[\![ 1,K]\!], \ \pi_n^{(i)} := \mathbb P(T_n=i) $$

One can see (prove it !) by using the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) that, for any $n$, the distribution of $T_n$ is given by
$$ \pi_n = \pi_0 \underbrace{P\ldots P}_{n \text{ times}} = \pi_0 P^n $$
So with this, we can get an explicit expression of the distribution of $T_n$ for any $n$.

As for your second question, yes, it is true that the chain will converge in distribution to the target distribution. I won't get into the details here, but the idea is to use a theorem that says that any irreducible and aperiodic Markov chain has a unique stationary distribution, and that it converges to it. So after proving that the Markov chain $(T_n)$ is irreducible and aperiodic, all that's left is to show that $f$ is indeed the unique stationary distribution of the chain (and it is true by construction).
More explanations on the proof of that amazing result are given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2923979/what-is-the-proof-guarantee-that-metropolis-hastings-converge-to-our-required)

Comment: thank you for the reply.  Just want to confirm that I understand your post. Your wrote: "the chain will converge in distribution to the target distribution. ", since we already know that the distribution of the sampling sequence $T_1, T_2, ..., T_n$ will converge to the target distribution. You mean that the distribution of $T_n$ itself also converge to the target distribution. Is it right ?

Comment: yes, that's right !

Comment: @StratoFair, thank you for the quick reply.  The distribution of $T_n$ converge to the target distribution, does this  converge happen to any target distributions ? or only certain distributions ? I am trying to see if any restrictions needed for the convergence, particularly for the purpose of mathematically rigorous.

Comment: For the convergence to happen, you need the Markov chain to be irreducible and aperiodic, which means that from any state $i \in [\![1,K]\!]$, you can reach any other state $j \in [\![1,K]\!]$. This implies that the transition kernel has to assign positive probability to any point in the state space. That will hold for most distributions you'd want to simulate in practical applications, but I guess you can create pathological cases where it doesn't.

Comment: thank you for the illustration.

Comment: For any target distribution, the distribution of $T_n$ will converge to it.  In MH algorithm, typically, the proposal density or jumping distribution is Gaussian distribution. And the step size for the next movement (if we regard MH as a random walk) is drawn from the Gaussian distribution.  So the $T_n$ can be considered as a "summation of Gaussian random variables",  but why is the summation is NOT a Gaussian random variable ? Intuitively, how to understand this ? is it because Accept or Reject mechanism in MH completely distorts the  "summation of Gaussian distribution" ?

Comment: Note that I made the assumption that **the state space $\mathcal S$ is finite** and can be identified as $[\![1,K]\!] $. This is crucial, otherwise you can't define the transition matrix $P$ and the distribution vector $\pi$. Now the Gaussian distribution is defined on $\mathbb R^d$, which is not finite. Convergence of M-H thankfully still holds in that case (although I'm not sure the exact distribution of the chain at time $n$ can be derived), and I suggest you give a read to chapter 7 of [this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-4145-2) for formal proofs.

Comment: thank you. I will take a look of the book.